# tabPadding pushes the tab to the right because of the tabIndicatorFullWidth

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tablayout

When I add tabPadding, it pushes the tab to the right because the tabIndicatorFullWidth is true. How can I keep the tabs within padding with full width?

The right side of the tab indicator is hidden, I can't see the rounded corner.

**xml**

```
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="@style/RoundedTabLayoutStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_layout_bg"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5">
```

**style**

```
    <style name="RoundedTabLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">

        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="tabTextColor">@color/unselectedColor</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="tabRippleColor">@null</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorGravity">center</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">40dp</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorAnimationDuration">1000</item>
        <item name="tabIndicator">@drawable/tab_round_line</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorAnimationMode">elastic</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorFullWidth">true</item>

    </style>
```

**@drawable/tab_layout_bg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/background_color" />
    <corners android:radius="6dp" />

</shape>
```

**@drawable/tab_round_line**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

[image: Screen shot]